# Does renaming and emptying all the content of a file before deletion make it unrecoverable?

Tags: deletion, data-recovery

When I delete a file, I rename it to `new.txt`, open the file in a text editor, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to delete all the content and save it as an empty file and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to permanently delete the file.

Can someone now recover the file with the actual content?

Comment: This is potentially covered under many of the realted posts in the right hand sidebar. It will depend on where your OS stores temporary files, old versions etc. Generally, a forensic examination **will** be able to retrieve older versions...

Comment: As the question is already covered, Should I delete it?

Comment: If you like. I think this one will give you the answer you need, but have a read through a few: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110786

Comment: Thank you, I have gone through the answers. I think my question is a little bit different and you already answered my question in your 1st comment.